# Programmatic control (or annotation) of Instruments?

Tags: ios, instruments

Are there calls available to turn Instruments on for a specific section of code, annotate it, or some such?

I'm looking to profile a specific chunk of code. Usually, I'd just try to set my inspection range as close as possible to that code. But there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Instruments version 4 added the DTPerformanceSession framework that lets you start and stop profiling in your code. I have not used it, and I'm not sure if it's available for iOS, but it's something to investigate.

If you want to limit profiling to a single method, you can create a custom instrument. Choose Instrument > Build New Instrument to create a custom instrument. You can tell Instruments to start tracing when you enter a method and stop tracing when you exit that method. A custom instrument provides less control, but you don't have to modify your application code to use it.